# How to find duplicates in a List to merge them

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I have a list of potential duplicates. I recognize the duplicates by their ID. The objects have childs and now I want to merge the duplicates so that the childs are only attached to one object. How would I best identify the duplicates, maybe with streams?

```
public class Foo {
  private String id;
  private Collection<String> childs;
}

  private Collection<Foo> mergeDuplicates(Collection<Foo> fooList) {
    /*this method should call the mergeChilds on found Duplicates,
    and return the processed Collection of Foos*/
  }

  private Foo mergeChilds(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Yeah, using streams it is possible and then collect the data into a Map

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collect them to a `Map` based on the `id` and merge the `children` using the `mergeFunction`. Then map them back to final objects as:

```
private Collection<Foo> mergeDuplicates(Collection<Foo> fooCollection) {
    return fooCollection.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Foo::getChildren, this::mergeChildren))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Foo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)); // collect accordingly
}
```

with the updated `mergeChildren` method implemented in the same class as :

```
private Collection<String> mergeChildren(Collection<String> foo1Children, Collection<String> foo2Children) {
    foo1Children.addAll(foo2Children);
    return foo1Children;
}
```

Note: The *mergeFunction*(`(a,b) -> {...}`) is executed only when the `id` based duplicates are identified.

Comment: Great solution, unless you want to control which duplicates you want to merge and which others you want to keep

Answer (score 2):

Map and rewire the children:

```
List<Obj> list = ...;
Map<Long, Obj> objectsById = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(obj -> {
    objectsById.merge(obj.getId(), obj,
        (oldv, v) -> {
            if (oldv != null) {
                v.getChildren().forEach(ch -> ch.setParent(oldv));
                return oldv;
            }
            return v;
    });
});
list = objectsById.values();
```

If there is just a getParent, no getChildren. or children are parent objects too, a second walk is needed to remove obsolete objects from the children (not appearing in the map).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed example for your use-case, hope it helps.
This finds the duplicate using streams and then append the children to the existing object.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pojo p1 = new Pojo("a", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c1", "c2")));
        Pojo p2 = new Pojo("a", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c3", "c4")));
        Pojo p3 = new Pojo("b", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c5", "c6")));

        List<Pojo> pojos = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
        pojos.add(p1);
        pojos.add(p2);
        pojos.add(p3);

        Set<Pojo> uniquePojos = new HashSet<>();

        pojos.stream().filter(p -> {
            boolean notExists = uniquePojos.add(p);
            if (!notExists) {
                for (Pojo up : uniquePojos) {
                    if (up.equals(p)) {
                        up.children.addAll(p.children);
                    }
                }
            }
            return notExists;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(uniquePojos);

    }
}

class Pojo {

    Pojo(String id, List<String> children) {
        this.id = id;
        this.children = children;
    }

    String id;
    List<String> children;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pojo other = (Pojo) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo [id=" + id + ", children=" + children.toString() + "]";
    }

}
```

You can run and check the result here https://onecompiler.com/java/3v2sj7qyb

Result:

```
[Pojo [id=a, children=[c1, c2, c3, c4]], Pojo [id=b, children=[c5, c6]]]
```